# Remove Time on Bootsrap DatePicker when loading data in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have bootstrap datepicker in my MVC 4 application. When I'm click this datepicker it show date like

```
2014/04/24
```

When load C# datetime to this date picker it shows

```
4/3/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

this is my MVC view Code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_provide = "datepicker"})
```

this is date format script in layout

```
$(function () {
            $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "yyyy/mm/dd";
            $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = $('html').attr('lang');
            $.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;
        });
```

this is Model :

```
Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Display(Name = "Maintenance Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public virtual DateTime date
```

Please help this,

Answer (score 0):

try using `date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` while returning the data from the controller to the view